# Bash scripting and comparing 2 directories - Beginner

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, git-bash

My problem is that i have to check what files are included in the `$directory`, then i have to make a new file with name specified by me and compare if the name doesn't already exist in this directory (compare 2 directories).

Below is my code:

```
directory=$(pwd -L "/$nameProject")
read -p "Enter repo name: " nameRepo

# Check if repo name exists in $directory

if [$(find "$directory/$nameProject" -path "$directory/$nameProject/*")==$("$directory/$nameProject/$nameRepo")]; then
    instruction..
fi
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 
if [[ ! -d "$directory/$nameProject/$nameRepo" && ! -f "$directory/$nameProject/$nameRepo"]] ; then
    mkdir "$directory/$nameProject/$nameRepo"
fi

You can split the above if loop into two and print appropriate error by removing   !

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are important to the shell. So is quoting. You need spaces around `[` and `==` and `]` (though `];` is ok). (Also technically the comparison operator is `=` and not `==`.).

Also `find` can return more than one result which will cause problems for your test.

If you want to test whether a directory (or file) with a given name exists then you don't need (or want) to use `find`. You can just use the `-d` and `-f` (and `-e`) tests of the `[` test binary/built-in directly<sup>([spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#), [bashref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-test))</sup>.

```
if [ -d path/to/directory ]; then
    echo "Was a directory"
else
    echo "Was not a directory"
fi
```